# Не работает многопоточность в клиент-серверном приложении на Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, клиент-сервер

На сервере:

```
static final int SocketServerPORT = 1880;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        System.out.println("Port: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        while(true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            count++;
            ServerThread socketServerThread = new ServerThread(socket, count);
            socketServerThread.start();
            System.out.println("Client " + count);
        }
    }
```

ServerThread наследуется от Extends и в нем есть метод:
public void run () {}, котором в цикле, принимается с клиента typeOfMessage и передается в switch, далее вызывается соответствующий метод.

На клиенте:

```
public class client<T>
{
    private static int port;
    private static String txtAddr;
    private static String typeOfMessage;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private static ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public client(String txtADdr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.txtAddr = txtADdr;
        this.port = port;
        socket = new Socket(this.txtAddr, this.port);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    public static <T> void sendDataArrayList(ArrayList<T> ob, String tMsg) throws IOException {

        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> void sendData(T ob, String tMsg) throws IOException {
                typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static<T> ArrayList<T> receiveArrayList(String tMsg) throws IOException {
        typeOfMessage = tMsg;

        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
            list = (ArrayList<T>)object;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static<T> Object sendLoginPassword(String l, String p, String tMsg) {
        Object object = null;
        String type = "";
        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(l);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(p);
            objectOutputStream.reset();
            object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }

    public static<T> String sendDataRegistration(T ob, String tMsg) {
        String response = "";

        typeOfMessage = tMsg;
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(typeOfMessage);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ob);
            objectOutputStream.reset();

            response = (String)objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при работе нескольких пользователей при отправке данных с клиента на сервер приложение подвисает и выкидывает такой exeption:java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нууууу.

```
private static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
private static ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
```

и тому подобное означает, что у вас **общие** переменные `objectOutputStream` и `objectInputStream` для всех клиентов. Поэтому понятно, что разные клиенты у вас читают из **одного и того же** потока. И понятно, что пришедшие данные делятся между ними случайным образом. То есть каждый клиент читает случайные куски сообщения.

Дайте каждому клиенту по собственному потоку, должно быть лучше. Проверьте, чтобы той же проблемы не было и в сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Мб проблема на стороне сервера

Возможно это является проблемой
"На один ObjectOutputStream должен приходиться ровно один ObjectInputStream" [источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/314034/249218)

P.S. на будущие учитесь читать не только код ошибки но и где она была вызвана. А если Спрашиваете и нечего об этом не знаете то лучше выложить весь текст который вылетает с ошибкой.